# GlassFish 4.1.1 Poolconnection and Resources bug

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm using glassfish 4.1.1 and i can't create a JDBC-Connection-Pool or JDBC-Resources is there any solution to fix this !

[While creating the connection pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk89c.png)

[Whilte adding the Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL7d9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is in the application interface, so when i used the line commande it works !

`asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --port {4848} --datasourceclassname  org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource --restype javax.sql.DataSource --property PortNumber={5532}:Password={password}:User={user_name}:ServerName={localhost}:DatabaseName={database_name}=org.postgresql.Driver {pool_name}`